# Getting different output on each execution

Tags: c++, arrays

I tried to implement number of inversions in an array, using merge sort.
Every time I execute this code, I get different value of the number of inversions. I am not able to figure out the reason for this. Please have a look at the code and tell me the mistake.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int count =0;

void merge(int A[],int start,int mid,int end)
{
    int size1 = mid-start+1;
    int size2 = end-(mid+1)+1;

    int P[size1];
    int Q[size2];

    for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
        P[i]=A[start+i];
    for(int j=0;j<size2;j++)
        Q[j]=A[mid+j+1];

    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int i =0;

    while(k<mid && l<end)
    {
        if(P[k]>Q[l])
        {
            A[i] = Q[l];
            l++; i++;
            count++;

        }
        else
        {
            A[i] = P[k];
            k++; i++;
        }
    }
}

void inversions(int A[],int start,int end)
{
    if(start!=end)
    {
        int mid = (start+end)/2;

        inversions(A,start,mid);
        inversions(A,mid+1,end);
        merge(A,start,mid,end);

    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {4,3,1,2,7,5,8}; 
    int n = (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int));

    inversions(arr,0,n-1);
    cout<<"The number of inversions is:: "<<count<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One problem is the elements of `A` that you write to in `merge`.  Since you're merging `A` from `start` to `end`, when you write out the merged values, which element should you start writing to (it isn't 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int i =0;

    while(k<mid && l<end)
    {
        if(P[k]>Q[l])
        {
            A[i] = Q[l];
            l++; i++;
            count++;

        }
        else
        {
            A[i] = P[k];
            k++; i++;
        }
    }
```

Few mistakes here, `i` starts from `start` and not `0`. `k` must loop from `0` till `size1` and not till `mid`. Similarly, `l` must loop from `0` till `size2` and not till `end`. You are incrementing `count` by `1` when `P[k] > Q[l]` but this is incorrect. Notice that all the elements in array `P` following the element `P[k]` are greater than `Q[l]`. Hence they also will form an inverted pair. So you should increment count by `size1-k`.

Also, the `merge` procedure should not only count the inversions but also merge the two sorted sequences `P` and `Q` into `A`. The first while loop `while(k<size1 && l<size2)` will break when either `k` equals `size1` or when `l` equals `size2`. Therefore you must make sure to copy the rest of the other sequence as it is back into `A`.

I have made the appropriate changes in `merge` and pasted it below.

---

```
void merge(int A[],int start,int mid,int end)
{
    int size1 = mid-start+1;
    int size2 = end-(mid+1)+1;

    int P[size1];
    int Q[size2];

    for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
        P[i]=A[start+i];
    for(int j=0;j<size2;j++)
        Q[j]=A[mid+j+1];

    int k = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int i = start;

    while(k<size1 && l<size2)
    {
        if(P[k]>Q[l])
        {
            A[i] = Q[l];
            l++; i++;
            count += size1-k;

        }
        else
        {
            A[i] = P[k];
            k++; i++;
        }
    }
    while (k < size1)
    {
        A[i] = P[k];
        ++i, ++k;
    }
    while (l < size2)
    {
        A[i] = Q[l];
        ++i, ++l;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int P[size1];
int Q[size2];
```

VLA (Variable length arrays) are not supported by C++. `size1` and `size2` are unknown during compile time. So, each time they get a different value and hence the difference in output.

Use `std::vector` instead

```
std::vector<int> P(size1, 0); //initialize with size1 size 
std::vector<int> Q(size2, 0); //initialize with size2 size
```

Comment: VLAs are a compiler extension for some compilers.  Their use is not the problem.